# Como redirecionar para o mesma posição do objeto depois do update

Tags: array, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Estou exibindo uma coleção de objetos randômicos na minha action index. No entanto os objetos são exibidos um de cada vez. Assim:

```
@objects = Object.order("RANDOM()").limit(1)
```

Na view index, eu posso enviar um comentário para esse objeto, só que quando envio o comentário, ele atualiza a página e por ser randômico ele exibe um novo objeto.

A dúvida é, como faço pra redirecionar na action create de comentário pra esse mesmo objeto, pra visualizar o que foi comentado?

Answer (score 0):

Bom, não entendi muito bem a lógica de se mostrar apenas 1 no `index`, seria mais interessante você utilizar o `show` do item em questão.

Mas enfim, à sua pergunta. Vá até o controller de `comentario`, no metodo `create` dele você verá um `redirect_to` após um `if`, o qual verifica se o `comentario` foi salvo. Altere qual pagina deseja que ele redirecione assim que for salvo o `comentário`, já que provavelmente você possúi uma relação entre `objeto` e `comentario`, informando o `id` do `objeto`. Ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
def create
    ...
    if @comment.save
        redirect_to objects_path(object_id: @comment.object_id)
    else
    ...
end
```

E no seu método `index` do `controller` de Object

```
if params[:object_id]
    @objects = Object.where(id: params[:object_id])
else
    @objects = Object.order("RANDOM()").limit(1)
end
```

Mais uma vez, isso é meio feio, gambiarra, digamos assim.
O ideal seria você utilizar o `show`, para mostrar apenas 1, na hora de chamar o método `index`, você chamaria o `show`, já com esse valor randômico. E no `redirect_to` do create de `Comment`, você passaria :

```
object_path(@comment.object_id)
```

ao invés de

```
objects_path(object_id: @comment.object_id)
```

Comment: Obrigado cara, funcionou. Também concordo contigo, mas nesse caso específico nem temos uma action show. Mas funcionou perfeitamente sua solução. Obrigado.

Comment: Denada, marca a resposta como resolvida.